# Is it possible to use a batch file to ping multiple IP addresses, each in its own window?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, ping

Can I create a batch file to ping multiple IP addresses, every IP address in new window. I don't want to open multiple windows and manually writing every single ping ping command.

ex: `ping 192.168.1.1 -t` in one window and `ping 192.168.2.1 -t` to another window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy, save the following to a [.bat] file:

```
@echo off
rem start two new ping command windows from a batch file:
START cmd /k ping 8.8.8.8 /t
START cmd /k ping 127.0.0.1 /t
```

This will open two new command windows, each continuously pinging two different IP Addresses [8.8.8.8 && 127.0.0.1]

Answer (score 4):

You can ping multiple IP addresses this way:

```
for /L %z in (1,1,254) do @ping 192.168.%z -w 10 -n 1 | find "Reply"
```

Change the IP address after the `ping` command to reflect your networks IP range. The above command will ping each address between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254 and return the IP address for reply to the ping.

The `-w 10` makes it only wait 10 ms for a reply before moving on. If your network is slow you will have to up this value or take it out altogether.

Pertaining to Greensonline's answer, Yes, I forgot the last octet. My mistake there.

However the second % sign does not work in Windows 10/11 command line. It errors with %%z was unexpected at this time.

Comment: This is a very cool command. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to ping multiple IP addresses [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org)

This program will ping your specified IP addresses, domain in a window, also display hostname and ports open.

Quick and easy to use rather than separate cmd windows all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `start` command.

For example, to ping the 2 addresses you gave:

```
start ping 192.168.1.1 -t
start ping 192.168.2.1 -t
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to [Brian's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1461334/399707), in order to use the command in a *batch file*, as opposed to on the *command line*, one would need to escape the `%`, with an additional `%`, like so:

```
for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do @ping 192.168.1.%%z -w 10 -n 1 | find "Reply"
```

The explanation as to why you need to escape the `%` is on SO, [What is the difference between % and %% in a cmd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14509652/4424636):

> 1. The percent sign is used in batch files to represent command line parameters: %1, %2, ...
> 2. Two percent signs with any characters in between them are interpreted as a variable:
>
>    ```
>     echo %myvar%
>    ```
> 3. Two percent signs without anything in between (in a batch file) are treated like a single percent sign in a command (not a batch file):
>    %%f

Note that the command in Brian's answer (as of [edit#2](https://superuser.com/posts/1461334/revisions)) is also missing the third octet of the IP address and should be:

```
192.168.1.%z
```

and not

```
192.168.%z
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install a utility `fping` which works in a round-robin way to ping each ip address. You can install it by:

```
sudo apt install fping
```

Then you can ping multiple addresses using one-liner:

```
fping <ip1> <ip2> <ip3>
```

It can also be used to run multiple ip addresses written down in a file. This can also fulfill your requirement of not writing the ips every time you need to ping.
Just to comply with the question to use a bash script, you can write it in a bash script too.

Comment: your solution is for linux but they are asking about windows batch files

Comment: fping is also available for windows.

Comment: didn't realize that @subtleseeker I'm trying it out now.